# Unescape quotes inside an XML string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, unescapestring

I want to unescape the quotes in the following XML/svg string.

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) --><svg    xmlns:inkscape=\"http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape\"    xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\"    xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"    xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\"    xmlns:ns1=\"http://sozi.baierouge.fr\"    xmlns:cc=\"http://creativecommons.org/ns#\"    xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\"    xmlns:sodipodi=\"http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd\"    id=\"svg2\"    sodipodi:docname=\"Leone.svg\"    viewBox=\"0 0 106.3 88.583\"    sodipodi:version=\"0.32\"    version=\"1.0\"    inkscape:output_extension=\"org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape\"    inkscape:version=\"0.46\"  >  <sodipodi:namedview      id=\"base\"      bordercolor=\"#666666\"      inkscape:pageshadow=\"2\"      inkscape:window-y=\"28\"      pagecolor=\"#ffffff\"      inkscape:window-height=\"944\"      inkscape:zoom=\"2.6756605\"      inkscape:window-x=\"0\"      showgrid=\"false\"      borderopacity=\"1.0\"      inkscape:current-layer=\"layer1\"      inkscape:cx=\"6.1097864\"      inkscape:cy=\"46.47492\"      units=\"cm\"      inkscape:window-width=\"1279\"      inkscape:pageopacity=\"0.0\"      inkscape:document-units=\"px\"  />  <g      id=\"layer1\"      inkscape:label=\"Livello 1\"      inkscape:groupmode=\"layer\"    >    <g        id=\"g3156\"      >      <path          id=\"path4510\"          sodipodi:nodetypes=\"ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccsscccsccscscscccsssccccccccscsccccccccccssccccccccccccccccc\"          style=\"fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0426px;fill:#000000\"          d=\"m101.23 24.143l2.72-2.638 0.4-3.182-3.73-1.472-6.097-0.821 1.426-5.929-6.106-5.4314-3.793 3.2775 0.605-4.4318-3.347-1.2118-3.739 3.7644-1.443-4.1326-1.905-0.2508-2.044 0.2022-1.854 5.2058-2.945-5.21-2.309 0.4864-2.4 1.0643 1.334 7.4398-6.944-3.2986-2.121 1.5779-1.209 2.1097 6.733 7.201-9.965-3.125-1.789 1.787-0.563 2.632 9.435 4.228-10.923 1.505-0.583 2.312-0.159 1.875 11.223 0.872-11.424 3.29-0.195 3.271-4.16 5.886c-4.597 5.556-11.327 7.66-16.777 9.718-2.735 1.033-7.075 0.397-9.567 1.917-2.698 1.644-6.517 8.212-6.517 8.212l-1.5252 9.993-1.8025-0.821s-0.0873-7.219 0.8319-10.13c1.3868-4.391 7.7648-13.277 7.7648-13.277 6.973-6.462 10.629-12.639 12.618-21.765 0.749-7.05-2.437-9.196-7.488-10.54-0.865-0.23-1.109-2.737-1.109-2.737s-5.387-2.244-7.765-1.917c-1.901 0.262-5.546 3.149-5.546 3.149s3.0819 4.621 4.16 5.338c1.811 1.205 5.546 0.137 5.546 0.137l3.605-1.232c4.775 1.695 4.667 3.376 4.714 7.392-1.111 6.45-5.558 13.02-11.37 19.026 0 0-7.7062 9.901-9.4281 14.784-1.4101 3.998-2.2622 9.621-1.5252 13.688 0.7535 4.158 3.5037 8.599 6.3781 12.593l43.815 0.17 1.664-4.687-1.387-3.285h-16.084c3.135-3.868 6.142-7.257 6.517-12.456-0.537-4.853-6.537-8.808-7.071-9.514l3.189-1.848s7.073 5.204 7.781 10.89c0.408 3.279-2.345 8.391-3.575 10.049 0 0 11.505-1.767 16.315-3.555 3.312-1.23 10.26-5.749 10.26-5.749l0.694 6.16 0.179 13.932 14.022-0.137 0.937-4.194c-0.928-4.846-3.918-3.681-7.961-4.713 0-0.548 1.142-8.858 1.142-8.858l2.634-7.802 13.727 5.065-0.138 5.064c1.381 4.244 3.491 3.646 5.273 3.149 1.66-0.466 2.52-4.297 2.63-5.065 0.08-0.606-2.91-8.487-2.91-8.487l-14.145-7.939 1.729-3.172-0.719-8.93 5.067 4.421 1.841-1.72-1.817-8.424 6.69-0.808 1.021-2.344-1.777-0.456-0.783-2.615-1.113 2.075-7.68-1.914 4.89-3.626 5.773-0.728 0.53 2.701 1.513-3.031z\"      />      <path          id=\"path2384\"          sodipodi:rx=\"3.6439602\"          sodipodi:ry=\"3.6439602\"          style=\"fill:#ffffff\"          sodipodi:type=\"arc\"          d=\"m123.89 16.358a3.644 3.644 0 1 1 -7.28 0 3.644 3.644 0 1 1 7.28 0z\"          transform=\"matrix(.69231 0 0 .69231 4.4849 4.8462)\"          sodipodi:cy=\"16.357512\"          sodipodi:cx=\"120.25069\"      />    </g    >  </g  >  <metadata    >    <rdf:RDF      >      <cc:Work        >        <dc:format          >image/svg+xml</dc:format        >        <dc:type            rdf:resource=\"http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage\"        />        <cc:license            rdf:resource=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain/\"        />        <dc:publisher          >          <cc:Agent              rdf:about=\"http://openclipart.org/\"            >            <dc:title              >Openclipart</dc:title            >          </cc:Agent          >        </dc:publisher        >      </cc:Work      >      <cc:License          rdf:about=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain/\"        >        <cc:permits            rdf:resource=\"http://creativecommons.org/ns#Reproduction\"        />        <cc:permits            rdf:resource=\"http://creativecommons.org/ns#Distribution\"        />        <cc:permits            rdf:resource=\"http://creativecommons.org/ns#DerivativeWorks\"        />      </cc:License      >    </rdf:RDF    >  </metadata  ></svg>"
```

But no matter what regex I try with `str.replace()`, the quotes stay escaped.
How do I unescape the quotes?

Comment: I suspect the backslashes aren't really in the string to begin with. How are you displaying the string?

Comment: Use `xmlVariable.contains("\\")` and see if it returns true, false, or an error. Each will tell you something about what type of variable you have.